# why es delete by query deleted more records

Tags: elasticsearch

There are below data in es

```
"id":1, "platform":"sougou_wechat", "screen_name":"aaa", "created_at":1530028800000
"id":2, "platform":"sougou_wechat", "screen_name":"bbb", "created_at":1530028800000
"id":3, "platform":"sougou_wechat", "screen_name":"ccc", "created_at":1530028800000
"id":4, "platform":"sougou_wechat", "screen_name":"aaa", "created_at":1529942400000
```

Now I want to delete records of screen_name in [aaa,bbb]

```
curl -XGET '127.0.0.1:9200/test/_search?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "query": { "bool": {"must" : [{"match":{"platform":"sougou_wechat"}}] , "filter" : { "terms" : { "screen_name" : ["aaa", "bbb"] } }, "filter":[{"range":{"created_at":{"gte":1530028800000,"lt":1530115200000} }}] } }
}
'
{
  "took" : 3,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "max_score" : 0.2876821,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "test",
        "_type" : "foo",
        "_id" : "2",
        "_score" : 0.2876821,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : 2,
          "platform" : "sougou_wechat",
          "screen_name" : "bbb",
          "created_at" : 1530028800000
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "test",
        "_type" : "foo",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 0.2876821,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : 1,
          "platform" : "sougou_wechat",
          "screen_name" : "aaa",
          "created_at" : 1530028800000
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

it indeed returns the `two` records I want to remove, but when I execute `delete_by_query` using the same query, why `three` records are deleted? it seems the second filter does not work because only the fourth record left.

```
➜  ~ curl -X POST "127.0.0.1:9200/test/_delete_by_query?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
quote> {
quote> "query": { "bool": {"must" : [{"match":{"platform":"sougou_wechat"}}] , "filter" : { "terms" : { "screen_name" : ["aaa", "bbb"] } }, "filter":[{"range":{"created_at":{"gte":1530028800000,"lt":1530115200000} }}] } }
quote> }
quote> '
{
  "took" : 210,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "total" : 3,
  "deleted" : 3,
  "batches" : 1,
  "version_conflicts" : 0,
  "noops" : 0,
  "retries" : {
    "bulk" : 0,
    "search" : 0
  },
  "throttled_millis" : 0,
  "requests_per_second" : -1.0,
  "throttled_until_millis" : 0,
  "failures" : [ ]
}
```

---

p.s. below query could correctly delete two records

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [{
            "match": {
                "platform": "sougou_wechat"
            }
        }, {
            "terms": {
                "screen_name": ["aaa", "bbb"]
            }
        }, {
            "range": {
                "created_at": {
                    "gte": 1530028800000,
                    "lt": 1530115200000
                }
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

---

p.s.

```
➜  ~ curl 'http://192.168.0.25:9200/test/_validate/query?explain=true&pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
quote> {
quote>     "query": { "bool": {"must" : [{"match":{"platform":"sougou_wechat"}}] , "filter" : { "terms" : { "screen_name" : ["aaa", "bbb"] } }, "filter":[{"range":{"created_at":{"gte":1530028800000,"lt":1530115200000} }}] } }
quote> }
quote> '
{
  "valid" : true,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "explanations" : [
    {
      "index" : "test",
      "valid" : true,
      "explanation" : "+platform:sougou_wechat #screen_name:aaa screen_name:bbb #created_at:[1530028800000 TO 1530115199999]"
    }
  ]
}
```

and the version I used

```
  "version" : {
    "number" : "5.5.2",
    "build_hash" : "b2f0c09",
    "build_date" : "2017-08-14T12:33:14.154Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "6.6.0"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is not correct, you have two times `bool/filter` and the second one (with the range) will override the first one (with the screen names)

Here is the correct query you need to use:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "platform": "sougou_wechat"
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "screen_name": [
              "aaa",
              "bbb"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "created_at": {
              "gte": 1530028800000,
              "lt": 1530115200000
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: but why the `_search` could return the correct records?

Comment: I suppose that the search overrides the second filter with the first one and delete by query does this opposite. The bottom line is that your query is not correct with two `bool/filter`, use mine and both the search and delete by query will work.

Comment: hi I have add more info in my post. it proves  that in search two filters both used, no overrides.

Comment: You **CANNOT** have two `filter` in a bool query. Fix your query and delete by query will work.

Comment: Try sending your search query to `127.0.0.1:9200/test/_validate/query?explain=true`. Update your question with the result you get and we'll see how ES handles it.

Comment: You didn't send the query to the validate endpoint. Keep your initial search query as it is, but replace `test/_search?pretty` by `test/_validate/query?explain=true` Please do so

Comment: Interesting issue, maybe a bug in ES 5, because in ES 6 the first filter gets overridden by the second one. However, you simply need to have a single filter section and everything works as you'd expect.